# Получить значение select

Tags: php, html

На странице показывает, что значение select не сохраняется в переменной examen

```html
   $examen = $_GET['dropdown'];
echo "<form method='get'>";
echo "<select id='dropdown' name='dropdown' onchange='top.location=this.value'>";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_row($students_result))
{
echo "<option value='http://exam/?students_id=$line[0]'>";
    echo " <a href = '?students_id=".$line[0]."' style = 'color:blue'> ".$line[1]." ".$line[2]." </a> ";
echo "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo " value = ' ".$examen." ' ";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
```

[image: subj]

Весь код, если понадобится, лежит здесь - [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/tmMhB3At)

Заранее извиняюсь, если решение лежит на поверхности и я просто в упор его не вижу.

Comment: попробуй: `$examen = $_GET['students_id'];`

Comment: в переменой `$examen` у вас не значение select, а $_GET параметр с названием "dropdown", которого как я подозреваю в вашей ссылке нету.